# Showing the change of basis matrix generates a spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider $Q$ an invertible $n\times$ matrix and $\beta=\{x_1,\dots ,x_n\}, \beta '=\{x_1',\dots , x_n'\}$ where

$$x_j'=\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{ij}x_j$$

We want to show that $\beta'$ is a basis for our vector space $V$ where $\beta$ is already a basis. I believe I have shown linear independence. We examine

$$a'_1x_1'+\dots +a'_nx'_n=0=a'_1\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{i1}x_1+\dots +a'_n\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{in}x_n$$

We know that some $Q_{ij}\neq 0$ since otherwise we have the $0$ matrix which is not invertible. Therefore we have some $a'_1c_1x_1+\dots +a'_nc_nx_n=0 \Rightarrow a'_i=0$ since the $c$'s are nonzero. Therefore $\beta'$ is linearly independent. Now, I need to show that any $x \in V$ is in span$(\beta')$. That is
$$x=a_1x'_1+\dots +a'_nx_n$$
We know
$$x=b_1x_1+\dots +b_nx_n$$ 
I am not quite sure how to move things around to make this work. My instinct is to try something like the following

$$x_j'=\sum_{i=1}^nQ_{ij}x_j \Rightarrow x_j=p_1x'_1-\sum_{i=2}^nQ_{ij}x_j$$

but this has some obvious wholes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error, I believe, in the above argumentation for linear independence is that despite the fact that we have some nonzero terms we may have $r_1x_1+n_1x_1+\dots$ where the sum there may be zero for each of the $x_i$'s so we can't assert what I have?

Answer (score 0):

Your linear independence argument has some holes in it: For linear independence we have
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i x_i'=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_i Q_{ij} x_j=
\sum_{j=1}^n x_j (\mathbf{c}^T Q)_j (*)$$
where $\mathbf{c}^T=(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$. Since $x_1, \cdots x_n$ is a basis, then they are linearly independent. i.e. if $\sum d_i x_i = 0$ then $d_i=0$. Note that equation (*) is simply $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i=0$ with $d_i = (\mathbf{c}^T Q)_i$. So we have $d_i=(\mathbf{c}^T Q)_i=0$ or in short $\mathbf{c}^T Q=0$ as a vector. Since $Q$ is invertible, multiply from right by $Q^{-1}$ to obtain $\mathbf{c}^T=0$, which means all $c_1, \cdots, c_n$ are zero.

For showing that $\{x_i'\}$ spans the whole thing, you only need to show that $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ can be obtained by linear combinations of $\{x_i'\}$. (Why?) By definition
$$x_i' = \sum_{j=1}^n Q_{ij}x_j
$$
Therefore by multiplying both sides with $Q_{ki}^{-1}$ (for some $k$ arbitrary) and summing over $i$ we obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} Q_{ki}^{-1}x_i' = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n Q^{-1}_{ki}Q_{ij}x_j=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j (Q^{-1}Q)_{kj}=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j \delta_{kj}=x_k$$

Comment: I do not understand your argument for linear independence. Also, where does my argument fail?

Comment: Your mistake as I just realized runs deeper: you wrote $x'_j = \sum_{i=1}^n Q_{ij}x_j$. This is wrong. The true formula is $x'_i = \sum_{j=1}^n Q_{ij}x_j$. The first formula is wrong for two reasons, first of all the summation index is the same as $x'_j$! Also $x_i$ does not depend on $j$ at all so you can factor it out.

Comment: Btw way if you fix this mistake (probably a type) then you see that you cannot repeat your linear independence argument anymore. Something goes wrong!

Comment: I also tried to write the linear independence argument more clearly, hope this is understandable now.